# Defining the size of .eps files with tex4ht

Tags: graphics, tex4ht

I'm working on a Latex document with which i generate both, an ebook and a pdf document. To include graphics i use the following config.cfg:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{graphics*}
{jpg}
{%  
   \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .jpg
      \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *2"
}%  
  \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg}
 }

\Configure{graphics*}
{png}
{%  
   \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png
      \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *2"
}%  
  \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
 }

\begin{document}
\CssFile[custom.css] 
/* css.sty */
\EndCssFile
\Configure{CoverMimeType}{image/jpg}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.png,.jpg,.gif,}
\EndPreamble
```

To include pdf graphics i converted all files to eps and leave out the file extensions in the latex document, so eps files are included when generating an ebook and pdf files are included when generating a pdf document. 
Is there a way to expand the eps graphics in the ebook, just as it was done above with jpg and png? It's not working if i just insert 'eps'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following configuration:

```
\Configure{graphics*}
{eps}
{%  
\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax 
  \ifeof15 
  \Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps 
    \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt"}% 
  \fi 
  \closein15 
   \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname \PictExt
      \space width="\the\dimexpr \expandafter\csname
Gin@req@width\endcsname *2"
}%  
  \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}
 }
```

(it is inspired by the [tex4ht troubleshooting page](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn3.html)

It tests for the existence of a version of the included file in the current output picture format (`PNG` or `SVG`) and calls ImageMagick's convert command only if it doesn't exist.